# Android JAVA navigate to fragment passing data with Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to navigate from a RecyclerView adapter to a detail fragment, passing an id value.

I can navigate from an item selected in the RecyclerView to open the GameDetailFragment using the following:

```
    this.cardGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NavDirections action = ScoreboardFragmentDirections.actionScoreboardFragmentToGameDetailFragment();
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action);
        }
    });
```

However, I can't seem to find how to pass data when clicking on the CardView item to the GameDetailFragment to query the details.

I can find many examples in Kotlin, but I'm just learning Java and Android and would rather not start with Kotlin.

Using the example from the documentation:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   EditText amountTv = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
   int amount = Integer.parseInt(amountTv.getText().toString());
   ConfirmationAction action = SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction();
   action.setAmount(amount);
   Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);
}
```

It seems it's inaccurate as the documentation indicates that the word "action" is added to the **END** of the class name.

I decided to look at the actual generated class file, without modifying it, of course. The word "action" is added to the **BEGINNING** of the class file name or combination of the originating and receiving destinations.

The result:

```
    this.cardGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String strTemp = "todo";
            ScoreboardFragmentDirections.ActionScoreboardFragmentToGameDetailFragment action = ScoreboardFragmentDirections.actionScoreboardFragmentToGameDetailFragment();
            action.setMessage(strTemp);
            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action);
        }
    });
```

P.S. Have you ever even tried to follow along with the documentation? There is very little, if any, flow to their descriptions.

One paragraph they're talking about cats & dogs, then the next paragraph they talk about apples and oranges. As a noobie/beginner, it's incredibly frustrating because somehow you have to figure out how they all interconnect/interrelate to one another.

Then, when we ask, we get snooty responses referring right back to the same documentation. Like really...

But, what do I know, I'm only a beginner.

Comment: I would recommend reading the official documentation before asking a generic question like this. They provide samples in both Java and Kotlin: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate

Comment: So if you've read the documentation, then you've [added an argument to your destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#define_destination_arguments), the very first step on that page? Please include your navigation graph code where you've done that.

Comment: Yeah, I added an argument to the destination. I already figured it out and have it working.